# how to load 2 functions in javascript at window.onload

Tags: javascript

I am just picking up on javascript and I need to load 2 functions that I want to use when the window loads.

One function captures the form name and UTM parameters while the other generates a unique number. All these on window.onload in javascript for an HTML page.

My script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var defaultHiddenFieldNameValue = "";

function getQueryStringParamValue(strQStrParam) {

var strURL = document.location.href;

var strQStrParamValue = "";

           if (strURL.indexOf('?') != -1)
           {
                       strQStrParamValue = strURL.substr(strURL.indexOf('?') + 1);
                       if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam) != -1)
                       {
                                   strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf(strQStrParam));
                                   strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(strQStrParamValue.indexOf('=') + 1);
                                   if (strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&') != -1)
                                   strQStrParamValue = strQStrParamValue.substr(0, strQStrParamValue.indexOf('&'));
                                   return strQStrParamValue;

                       }else{
                                   strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
                                   return strQStrParamValue;
                       }
           }else{
                       strQStrParamValue = defaultHiddenFieldNameValue;
                       return strQStrParamValue;
           }
}

// Form name goes here
var form = "formname";

function setCampaign(){

  var elqForm = document.forms[form];

  //repeat for each field to populate
    document.forms["formname"]["val1"].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_source');
    document.forms["formname"]["val2"].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_medium');  
    document.forms["formname"]["val3"].value = getQueryStringParamValue('utm_campaign');
}


function VisitorID() {
  var min = 1;
  var max = 9999999999;
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  document.getElementById('field16').value = num + '_' + timeNow;
}

function both() {
  function VisitorID();
  function setCampaign();
}

window.onload = both;
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the two *function* syntax errors and itll work fine..

Answer (score 1):

```
function both() {
  function VisitorID();//syntax error
  function setCampaign();
}
```

The *function* keyword just goes before *function declarations*. If you want to call them you dont need them (they throw an error):

```
function both() {
  VisitorID();
  setCampaign();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonas, works amazing !! Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @Arun if the answer helped you, then click the green tick below the voting buttons

Answer (score 1):

You can not call functions with prefix `function` in it. That will declare the function. 
Change last few lines from this -

```
function both() {
  function VisitorID();
  function setCampaign();
}

window.onload = both;
```

to this -

```
function both() {
  VisitorID();
  setCampaign();
}

window.onload = both();
```

if you want both functions to get executed.